# Why is this code for Oracle Database not working?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In my case functions `PROCESS_OPERATOR` and `PROCESS_WHERE` calls each other, but this code is compiled with errors

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PROCESS_OPERATOR
(
  p_operator IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  l_result VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  l_result := PROCESS_WHERE('test');
  RETURN l_result;
END;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PROCESS_WHERE
(
  p_where IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  l_result VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  l_result := PROCESS_OPERATOR('test');
  RETURN l_result;
END;
```

Errors:

```
PLS-00905: object SYS.PROCESS_WHERE is invalid
PLS-00905: object SYS.PROCESS_OPERATOR is invalid
```

How to make functions call each other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to declare two functions that call each other then use a package:

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE package_name IS
  FUNCTION x(n IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;
  FUNCTION y(n IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER;
END;
/
```

then

```sql
CREATE PACKAGE BODY package_name IS
  FUNCTION x(n IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('x: ' || n);
    RETURN CASE WHEN N > 0 THEN y(TRUNC(n/2)) ELSE 0 END;
  END;

  FUNCTION y(n IN NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('y: ' || n);
    RETURN CASE WHEN N > 0 THEN x(n-1) ELSE 0 END;
  END;
END;
/
```

Then you can call it using:

```sql
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(PACKAGE_NAME.X(20));
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> x: 20
> y: 10
> x: 9
> y: 4
> x: 3
> y: 1
> x: 0
> 0
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5aVcALCx)

Answer (score 3):

1. I see you have created your objects as the SYS user. NEVER do that: the SYS schema is reserved for Oracle's data dictionary and other internal programs. It should never contain custom application code. Create a separate user/schema to hold "your" code.
2. The first function cannot compile because the second one does not yet exist. Similarly, the second one fails to compile because the first one failed and also does not exist. To have this kind of relationship, you need to embed your functions in a package so that everything is compiled at the same time.
3. That said, what is the purpose of this example, since it would only spawn an infinite loop and result in a runtime error or system hang as soon as either function was called?